# when repo sync, it stop at Fetching projects: 100% (293/293), done

Tags: android, repository

I make a new repo for Android OS source.I want download the Android4.1.1

I used:

repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-4.2_r1

repo sync

after hours ,the terminate shows:

yeling@yeling-ThinkPad-E420:~/code/Android4.1$ repo sync

Fetching projects: 100% (293/293), done.

and it stoped here, i entered the directory ~/code/Android4.1/ ,there are no files, only a directory .repo

Answer (score 8):

Use

$ repo sync -l

It only updates working tree and does not fetch.

Check out $repo sync -h, for other options of repo sync.

Have fun!
Rakesh Verma